# Manual Update 500 error

Tags: config, updates, manual-updates

Downloaded latest release, pushed app-new to server, renamed app to app-old, renamed app-new to app.

Try to go to admin, and I get a 500 error.

Server error log shows.
2017-11-15 12:29:29 Error   500 GET /admin HTTP/1.1

Any ideas.
Trying to update an install that hasn't been updated in a long time.
Going from 2.6.2911 to 2.6.2974

I can still get to admin if I use the old app by renaming app to app-new, and app-old to app

Comment: If it's a Craft-styled 500 Internal Server Error, the underlying message should be in your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files.

Comment: It's not a craft syled 500 error

Comment: If you open your browser's console, go to the network tab, do you get anything back in the response to the request that causes the 500?

Comment: Just noticed the download from craft site is 2.6.2997 vs the download button on site I'm trying to update gave me 2.6.2974 not sure why that is but will try the one from craft site.

Comment: Ok when I try to update to 2.6.2977 I at least get a message You need to be on at least Craft CMS 2.6.2922 before you can manually update to Craft CMS 2.6.2997. I will try the download again for 2.6.2974 maybe it's corrupt.

Comment: Alright, re-downloaded the first one, uploaded it worked, then was able to update again to 2977. Must have been a corrupt download or something.

Comment: Fair enough... would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer in case it helps someone else in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Re-downloaded manual update, and pushed to the server via ftp again fixed the issue. Download might have been corrupt is my only thought.